# Access values in the header, using the Flow external services actions

Tags: visual-workflow, external-services

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to use the flow external services components and retrieve values that are passed back in the response header.

Specifically, the Campaign Monitor Transactional Emails API are rate limited, and they pass how close you are to hitting the rate limit in the header. Here is [a link](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/v3-3/getting-started/#rate-limiting) to that documentation.

```
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 0
X-RateLimit-Reset: 348
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to monitor these values and then pause or end a flow before hitting the cap.